# How to segregate data into 3 different time (24 hours) frame using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, time, frame

first and foremost ,  im using SQL. only SQL query language. I am using MYSQL workbench to extract some features needed for my project. I have managed to extract the features needed and store it in a new table call new event. I have also converted the time into integer. Below is the sql code used :-

```
select iphdr.cid ,iphdr.ip_dst, date(event.timestamp), convert(time(event.timestamp), unsigned) as newtime, event.signature 
from iphdr, event
where iphdr.cid = event.cid
order by event.signature;
```

result (some of the output)

```
cid |ip_add      |date        |newtime|sig. 

480 | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |4328   | 1   
482 | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |4328   | 1   
1   | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |113928 | 1   
2   | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |235959 | 2
```

Since I have converted the time into numeric; hence newtime, now i need to segregate the output form the query above into three different time frame within the period of 24 hours (time frame 0 , 1 and 2). Here is the problem .... when i try to do it using the codes (below) i keep getting the 1064 error code. I thought that by using IF then Else , i could easily separate the data into 3 different time frame.
The output i need is like below

```
cid |ip_add      |date        |newtime|sig.   |time Frame
480 | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 | 4328  | 1  | 0
482 | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |4328   | 1  | 0
1   | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |113928 | 1  | 1
2   | 3232284675 | 2011-11-19 |235959 | 2  | 2
```

Below is the code i used was suppose to do that, however i keep getting error code 1064.

```
 select newtime from new_event for every row
 IF newtime < 80101
  than newtime = 0
 else if newtime > 80000 and newtime  < 160101 than newtime = 1
 else if newtime >160000 than newtime = 2
 end if
```

I hope im making more sense. Im a complete klutz when it comes to programming. im sorry .
Im also trying to make this work by browsing the net. Ill be working hard while waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (newtime>160000, 2, if(newtime>80000, 1, 0))
```

I misunderstood previously, if you not looking to break into 8 hours frame,
the above should help

Comment: thank you, so very much. I have got it, finally. I can go sleep now.

Comment: no, this is the wrong syntax, just `select if (newtime>160000, 2, if(newtime>80000, 1, 0)) as time_frame from new_event;`

Answer (score 0):

you could enclose your query within a subselect, if you still need newtime. (Just pseudo code, please use the appropriate syntax to your database)

```
select *, newtime / 3 as segment
FROM "your-query"
```

in mysql consider using TIME

```
SELECT TIME(event.timestamp) / 3 as seqment
```